# What's the advantage of using Grouper over AD or LDAP?

Tags: authorization, middleware

I'm reading the documentation on [Grouper](http://www.internet2.edu/grouper/), but I can't for the life of me figure out what the benefit of grouper is over storing groups in AD or LDAP. Can anyone shed light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears grouper allows you to delegate group management to end-users which may make sense for distribution lists, etc.
FWIW, AD already provides this functionality natively through Outlook (and proper permissions)

I don't know what OpenLDAP offers in this regard.